# Modal and separable verb

Tags: modal-verb, separable-verb

Suppose I am building a modal sentence with a separable/trenbare verb. Does the verb at the end of the sentence still get separated ?

Is it "Ich muss gehen zurück"

Or "Ich muss zurückgehen" ?

Comment: The plain infinitive is never separated for separable verbs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The separable verb is only separated when it's used in second position in a main clause. In all other cases (last position in a subclause, as infinitive or participle) it's not separated. However, the past participle marker -ge- is inserted in between the prefix and the verb.

> Ich gehe zurück.
>
> Ich muss zurückgehen.
>
> ..., weil ich zurückgehe.
>
> Ich bin zurück**ge**gangen.

Answer (score 1):

When modal verbs are used, the separable verbs stay intact:

> E.g. Ich muss heimgehen.

When the separable verbs are used by themselves, they separate:

> E.g. Ich komme heim.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what if it in relative construction is like: "er,der kommt heim." is this work somehow?

Comment: Er, der gerade erst heimgekommen ist, ist mein Mann.

Comment: What if it is in present contruction like: "er, der jetzt kommt heim." or "er,der jetzt heimkommt" which works?

Comment: The second one, dude